# Spawn a thread inside a sub-process in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a group of 60 objects, each of which i want to have its own `threading.Thread`. In order to break this down even further because of Python's locking and whatnot, I wanted to spawn sub-processes (using `multiprocessing.Process`), and use 6 `Threads` per `Process`. I broke my objects out into a two-dimensional `list` to make them easier to loop through, such that obj[] indices represent the `Process` number and each element in obj[][] is one of the objects I am working with as `Threads`. So here's the breakdown:

```
# break the objects out into my 2D list
obj= []
for i in all_obj:
  if len(obj) == 0 or len(obj[len(obj)-1]) > 5:
    obj.append([])
  obj[len(obj)-1].append(i)

# spawn processes 
processes = []
for i in obj:
  processes.append(Process(target=proc_run,args=(i))
  processes[len(processes)-1].start()

# process target
def proc_run(my_objs):
  threads = []
  for ad in my_objs:
    threads.append(Thread(target=thread_run,args=(ad))
    threads[len(threads)-1].start()

# thread target
def thread_run(my_obj):
  for i in range(1,21):
    ## do some stuff with the object here
    pass
  logging.info("Thread for object <%s> finished."%(my_obj.prop))
```

The problem is that the threads are not actually spawning unless I add the `join()` after the `start()` call. Since this eliminates my desire to multithread (i could just use a `for` loop and accomplish the same thing), I'm not entirely sure what to do.

I'm a total noob when it comes to this threading stuff, so the more dumbed-down you can make your answers, the easier it will be for all involved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Python basically uses threading to spawn the processes, I just decided to use 60 processes. This should allow for (basically) the same thing I am aiming for; it will just make the processes tab in task manager blow up a bit. ;)

Comment: You might want to "accept" your answer (click the check mark beside it). That will show that it is what you believe to be the (best) answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to but it says I can't for two days. That's rather annoying, I know, but what are ya gonna do?

Answer (score 1):

`Process` (in at least some versions of `multiprocessing`) kills the process (thus, all the threads) as soon as the `target` function returns.  You do need to `join()` to make that happen only after the threads finish, but you put that `join()` outside the loop so that you wait *while* they are all running.